# android open source - how to setup android self compiled on my device

Tags: android, mobile

I want to compile android version and setup this version on my device.
I have Samsung s7 but in case this device can't be setup with self compile version - what device can be use for this ?

Comment: Please define clearly what does "self compile version" mean.

Comment: @MorrisonChang self compile version is version that i will download the source ( open source ) of the android and will compile it and will install on my device

Comment: So you are looking for "Custom ROM". Full steps for those on any device is too long and out of scope for StackOverflow. Related info: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65557/is-there-a-technical-reason-android-update-story-is-so-bad?rq=1 and https://source.android.com/

Comment: "Custom ROM" is exactly a compile of Custom  source code  ?

Comment: Please use search: https://www.xda-developers.com/what-is-custom-rom-android/

Comment: Or buy a Google Nexus/Pixel device if you want "easy" path to build AOSP. Drivers found here: https://developers.google.com/android/drivers